# Require.js Uncaught TypeError: jqOAuth is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, requirejs

I would like to use [jQuery OAuth](https://github.com/esbenp/jquery-oauth) library in my application.

Right now I'm trying to initialize it in `main.js` file.

I defined paths for this lib and it's dependency [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js):

```
requirejs.config({
   paths: {
    store: "../Scripts/store.min",
    jqueryOAuth: "../Scripts/jquery.oauth"
   }
});
```

And I took an example from jQuery OAuth page how to do an initialization:

```
define(["store", "jqueryOAuth"], function (store, jqOAuth) {
    if (!store.enabled) {
        alert("Store not enabled");
        return;
    }

    var auth = new jqOAuth({ // <--- Uncaught TypeError: jqOAuth is not a function
        events: {
            login: function() {},
            logout: function() {},
            tokenExpiration: function() {}
        }
    });
});
```

When I open my website I get the error in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: jqOAuth is not a function`

But if you take a look at [jquery.oauth.js](https://github.com/esbenp/jquery-oauth/blob/master/src/jquery.oauth.js#L1) file, you'll see, that there's a function called jqOAuth.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I'm quite new to javascript stuff and maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that I was overriding global `jqOAuth` function with my local variable of the same name.

Here's working code:

```
define(["store", "jqueryOAuth"], function (store) {
    if (!store.enabled) {
        alert("Store not enabled");
        return;
    }

    var auth = new jqOAuth({
        events: {
            login: function() {},
            logout: function() {},
            tokenExpiration: function() {}
        }
    });
});
```